# Firebase Realtime Database: Good Practice (Filter, Ordering, etc..)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am beginner on Firebase (and beginner on NoSQL).
I would like to learn the good practices about filtering data.
For example with this simple realtime database:

[image]

How you would go about filtering this posts?

**Example 1**: List all posts (without any filter):

```
firebase.database().ref('post/').once('value').then((snapshot) => {

});
```

**Example 2:** List all posts order by createdAt and limit at 3:

```
firebase.database().ref('post/').orderByValue('createdAt').limitToLast(3).once('value').then((snapshot) => {

});
```

**Example 3:** List all posts order by createdAt, endAt(1605972663986) and limit at 3:

```
firebase.database().ref('post/').orderByValue('createdAt').endAt(1605972663986).limitToLast(3).once('value').then((snapshot) => {

});
```

But:

- How can I get all posts of user "et6e1AKrhk2GwqjCAKUHK5Bjlgu2" order by "createdAt" and limit at 3 ?
- How can I get all posts in category [9, 12] order by "createdAt" ?
- How can I get all posts exclude category [2, 4] order by "createdAt" ?
- Should I retrieve all the posts and then filter them myself? (is it a good way? if I have 100 millions of posts, what should I do ?)

Sorry If my questions look like stupid but I am 100% beginner and I don't know not yet the goods practice (Currently I have over 1000 messages and I need to filter [with pagination] them based on the current user settings).

Thank you

Comment: This is not a *Here's my list of questions* site. It's a question and answer site. Please note that *question* is singular, not plural. If you have more than one question, you need to ask in more than one post.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase charges per document read, so reading 100 million posts at once wouldn’t be a good idea as I’m sure you know.

The query questions you asked seem rather simple and should not be a problem. Firebase does have limitations on queries and you should review all the documentation.

When I started with Firebase I used real-time database initially but eventually switch to Cloud Firestone as I found the querying to be much more powerful using `where` conditions. (Fire store also has some major limitations: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations )

It may be necessary to add fields to your documents for the sole purpose of filtering and querying. Sometimes it works out where you need to sort data client side, which shouldn’t be a big deal.

I suggest you run tests to ensure you can query all data properly and add fields and ensure the DB fits your needs/research limitations before you dive in too deep! Your DB structure looks good!

Comment: Kumo : Thank you for your reply and your explain.

If I understand correctly, we should not use Firebase Realtime Database if we need to filter the data. Right?  

So I need to migrate my Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore. Thank you

Comment: After all, I wonder if it might not be more interesting to use MySQL. It allows me to do WHERE, ORDER BY, LIMIT conditions more easily than fight with NoSQL. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql